# Has anyone found a Google gadget for google desktop that shows top process usage.

Tags: software-rec, google-desktop-search, desktop-gadget

I want something like this Vista gadget: [TopProcess](http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=681102c2-5dde-44d2-a33a-96dbff32517a) to put in my google desktop sidebar

Comment: you want it for what OS? or are you looking for something that lives in your browser?

-1 not enough information

Comment: http://desktop.google.com/plugins/

Comment: If you're willing to use a seperate program, Samurize has plugins that can achieve this, as well as mostly everything GDS can do, except search.

Comment: I wanted a gadget because I already use a few of them and have space left in my sidebar.

Comment: I found a VMware CPU tracker, but I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

or this one : [Resource hog tracker](http://desktop.google.com/plugins/search/?query=hog&hl=en) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Um, so where is it? You just linked to the gadgets directory...

Comment: @musicfreak - the link resolves to http://desktop.google.com/plugins/i/processcheck_cumakt.html?hl=en for me

Comment: I think he is referring to http://desktop.google.com/plugins/i/processcheck_cumakt.html?hl=en

Comment: This is the best one so far.

Comment: @Revolter, all the links you listed are dead. Refreshing them would be appreciated.

Comment: well .. Google Desktop has been discontinued :/ http://googledesktop.blogspot.com/2011/09/google-desktop-update.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are really concerned about the memory utilization on your system,
you would not keep such gadgets active on your desktop in the first place.

This is what I would suggest for tracking process utilization,
All of these are listed on this [light-weight CPU usage monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/30452/lightweight-cpu-usage-monitor) question.

1. [TinyResMeter](http://perso.accelance.net/~pesoft/trm/us_trm.html) -- for light weight memory utilization tracking.
   Or, setup the [Moo0 System Monitor](http://www.moo0.com/?top=http%3A//www.moo0.com/software/SystemMonitor/%23SystemMonitor).
   When you get concerned about the memory utilization shift to Process Explorer
2. [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) -- keep this handy,
   and start it when you need to identify who is taking up memory.

Its usually not a big guess as to who is using the top memory
if you have Firefox and some AV tools running.

When you do get troubled with some top-resource-user,
its usually more than processor and RAM utilization you want to analyze
([procexp.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is quite good in such times)

---

Update: If you **do** want to [implement a Gadget](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Desktop-Developer) for this purpose,
The Sysinternals Suite has a tool  called [**`pslist`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx)
that can be used to 
get the top memory users like this (I am using this from a Cygwin shell),

```
 pslist -m | sort -n -k 4 | tail -3
```

That gave me an output like

```
pslist v1.28 - Sysinternals PsList
Copyright © 2000-2004 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals

svchost  1716  215996   32552   20276  166788   164579     74  145
explorer 2620  199768   53236   58272   69596  1034872     29  177
firefox  3408  225032  140324  126876  140164   161522     28   83

#header line patched in for reference
#Name     Pid      VM      WS    Priv Priv Pk   Faults   NonP Page
```

Comment: I'm well aware of other third party products. I wanted a Google gadget, that's why I asked for one.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not for Google Desktop, but Windows Sidebar has a low memory usage CPU and RAM meter. Otherwise, use a small program, not a gadget, like Moo0 System Monitor.

Get Vista sidebar in XP (just some possibilities, they might or might not work):
http://vista-sidebar-xp.en.softonic.com/

http://www.downloadsquad.com/2008/11/17/get-the-vista-sidebar-in-xp/ - this ones looks pretty good

http://techblissonline.com/vista-sidebar-windows-xp/

Of course, should you not want to the vista sidebar (which is actually semi-cool)...

Comment: I have winxp so no sidebar gadgets for me

Comment: Actually, you can use the vista sidebar, see above

Comment: I read some of the comments at softonic. It seems that there are problems adding new gadgets to it

Comment: Did you try all my links?

Comment: You could just try it and see if it works.