# Acer Aspire One AOA 150 netbook health monitoring software

Tags: windows-7, monitoring, acer-aspire-one

I have a Acer Aspire One AOA 150 with Windows Xp Home. I want to  monitor the voltages from the power supply, the temperature of the system,  the CPU and fan speeds. Much like the functionality of GKrellM(though I haven't used this on the netbook yet) , a GTK applet designed to make an impressive panel of monitors or xsensors in Linux.  Is this  possible with the netbook? I want a software for Windows 7 and Windows Xp.

Comment: This question also discusses some options that may be suitable for a netbook: http://superuser.com/questions/30452/lightweight-cpu-usage-monitor

Answer (score 0):

It's not very comprehensive, but [Taskbar Meters](http://taskbarmeters.codeplex.com/) may be of interest for Windows 7.

[Moo0 SystemMonitor](http://www.moo0.com/software/SystemMonitor/) is an option similar to GKrellM, that should work on Windows XP and 7.

Comment: what about Windows Xp